# Checkbox click event execution order and render

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I come into an interesting issue with the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.cache.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
        var c = function(){
                  console.log('checked:' + $('#test').attr('checked'));
                };
        $('#test').click(c);
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="test" type="checkbox" value="1">test
  </input>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is when I manually clicked the checkbox, it will print

```
checked:true
checked:false
checked:true
checked:false 
....
```

but if I trigger the click event with js code like:

```
$('#test').click()
```

it will print like

```
checked:false
checked:true
```

Sounds like for manually clicking, the checkbox itself would be rendered as checked/unchecked, then trigger the click event.

But, for JS code of `.click()`, this is not the case.

Is my guess right? Is there any documentation I can refer to for help?

Comment: Just a side note: jQuery is up to 1.8.2 now.

Comment: Another side note: `<input>` elements aren't supposed to have content (but most browsers won't get too upset about a closing `</input>` tag).

Comment: Could not reproduce the issue using jQuery 1.8.2, [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBFDU/).

Comment: I'm using 1.8.2 and firefox/firebug, I can reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue is when I manually clicked the checkbox, it will print
>
> checked:true
>   checked:false

I get:

```
> checked:true
> checked:undefined
```

The `attr` method is pretty awful (it used to confuse attributes and properties, probably still does), either read the property directly or use `prop`. It's far more efficient to write:

```
   console.log('checked:' + this.checked);
```

Anyhow, here's my former comment:

Probably because jQuery uses it's own event registration and firing framework that bypasses the DOM methods. When manually clicking the button, you get the DOM sequence of events. When using jQuery, you get jQuery's sequence of events.

Comment: for older jquery version, .attr('checked') will return false if it's un-checked. for newer version like 1.8.x, it's undefined.   I tried using "this.checked", same issue.

Comment: If `attr` is a surrogate for `getAttribtue` in this case, then it should return the string "null", because the *checked* attribute is not present, nor is it added by checking the checkbox. The checked *attribute* sets the default checked status of the checkbox, not its current checked status, hence jQuery's `attr` method has been broken since the start and still is (because it tries to mix getting and setting attributes with reading and setting DOM properties and deal with cross browser issues all without the programmer knowing what is going on).

Comment: the main issue of this question is not about diff between .prop() VS .attr().  It's all about the click event execution/checkbox render order .

Comment: No, but it highlights that jQuery sometimes does its own thing that is not consistent with W3C specifications or *de facto* browser standards. There have been many criticisms of `attr` over the years, and despite updates, it's still broken.